# LEFT OUTER JOIN keep all matched results from first table use where just for second table

Tags: mysql, select, join, where-clause

When I try to execute the mysql query below here I won't return all the record id's giving in the WHERE clause.

What I am trying to do:

1. Get all result records by id (IN)
2. JOIN the second table (websites_thumbs) By website_salt of Table 1 record result

   *By salt of the record from table 1 but also a salt from the parent site ($parent_salt)*
3. SUM votes and return in record result (if no result in the second table is found return 0)

ID 119 and 250 are having voting results in the second table, the others doesn't. The problem
I got is when I execute the query it returns just the records 1,119 & 250 the other id's are existing but they are not returned?

The query:

//  VxZQ85cByb98wUx0f3 => parent salt coming from another query (page data query)

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE t.thumb when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as thumbs_up,
    SUM(CASE t.thumb when -1 then 1 else 0 end) as thumbs_down,
    w.*, t.*
FROM websites as w
  LEFT OUTER JOIN websites_thumbs AS t 
  ON t.similar_website_salt = w.salt AND t.website_salt = 'VxZQ85cByb98wUx0f3' 
WHERE w.id IN ('1', '20', '31', '4', '199', '250', '633953')
GROUP BY t.similar_website_salt
```

first table

[image]

second table
[image]

Executing result

[image]

Hope someone can help me with this on!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` try `INNER JOIN`. Also, don't use `'` in the `IN` clause. Lastly, I changed the order of your `JOIN` just because I'm picky :)

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE t.thumb when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as thumbs_up,
    SUM(CASE t.thumb when -1 then 1 else 0 end) as thumbs_down,
    w.*, t.*
FROM websites as w
  INNER JOIN websites_thumbs AS t 
  ON w.salt = t.similar_website_salt AND t.website_salt = 'VxZQ85cByb98wUx0f3' 
WHERE w.id IN (1, 20, 31, 4, 199, 250, 633953)
GROUP BY t.similar_website_salt
```

It's kind of hard to say without seeing table schema, so if you want to throw some of that up there it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `GROUP BY` is eliminating any rows with a null `similar_website_salt`.  You need to change the `null` value to something else (e.g. empty string), and then group by that. Note there are two lines with the `COALESCE` addition:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE t.thumb when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as thumbs_up,
    SUM(CASE t.thumb when -1 then 1 else 0 end) as thumbs_down,
    w.*, t.*,

    COALESCE(t.similar_website_salt, '')

FROM websites as w
  LEFT OUTER JOIN websites_thumbs AS t 
  ON t.similar_website_salt = w.salt AND t.website_salt = 'VxZQ85cByb98wUx0f3' 
WHERE w.id IN ('1', '20', '31', '4', '199', '250', '633953')

GROUP BY COALESCE(t.similar_website_salt, '')
```

Comment: Tried exactly but the rows with a null similar_website_salt value are still eliminated from the result set. The strange thing is that the first record with id 1 is returned and has no record in the second table (so this one is not eliminated?)

Comment: @Freshtea - my changes were a bit ongoing. Did you happen to see that there are two COALESCE line additions?

Comment: @Freshtea - also, your screen shots only show 1 record in the first table. Can you change your snap to show another of the rows that is getting eliminated?

Comment: yes I saw both, I added a snap with the executing results. In the first table (main table) I have a couple of million records.

Comment: @Freshtea - Do you really mean to join on `t.similar_website_salt = w.salt`? Looking at your latest snap, it seems maybe that you should be using `t.website_salt = w.salt`. I could be wrong on that though. Other than that, I cannot think of what could be the problem.

Comment: Thanks, It's really what I need to heave. I try to describe it better for you. I have a page with data of 'one' website (the search action), there we have search results of similar websites. People can vote (by thumbs) on a result to tell us if the search result is similar to the the website of the search action. It's possible the same website from search results can be thumbed by another search action aswel, but in this case we don't want the tumbs from another search action. You can image? Sounds a little complex maybe :/

Comment: I got it work. The query was oke but the group had to be w.id ! :) thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Not all records are having a sub record in the second table so we can't
GROUP BY t.similar_website_salt and keep records in the result set without
this value.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE t.thumb when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as thumbs_up,
    SUM(CASE t.thumb when -1 then 1 else 0 end) as thumbs_down,
    w.*, t.*
FROM websites as w
  LEFT OUTER JOIN websites_thumbs AS t 
  ON t.similar_website_salt = w.salt AND t.website_salt = 'VxZQ85cByb98wUx0f3' 
WHERE w.id IN ('1', '20', '31', '4', '199', '250', '633953')
//GROUP BY t.similar_website_salt
GROUP BY w.id <-- this does the trick
```